# Odoo 10 Print multiple reports with one click

Tags: printing, report, odoo-10

Is there any way to print more than one report by one click in Odoo 10? For example i have one report template and some employees. Each employee should has own report with same template. And i want to print all report by one button.

I created template and python file. But could not print for each employee. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

you must have to extend qweb report like this

```py
class orders_print(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(orders_print,self).__init__(cr,uid, name, context=context)

class SaleOrderReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.sale.report_saleorder'
    _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
    _template = 'sale.report_saleorder'
    _wrapped_report_class = orders_print

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, docids,data=None,context=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('sale.report_saleorder')
        if data['data']:
            d = ast.literal_eval(data['data']['options'])
            docs = self.env[report.model].browse(d['ids'])
            docargs = {
                'doc_ids': self._ids,
                'doc_model': 'sale.order',
                'docs': docs,
            }
            return report_obj.render('sale.report_saleorder', docargs)
        else:

            return super(SaleOrderReport,self).render_html(docids,data=data)
```

Comment: This is old api, isn't it?

Comment: No it is new api.